Can't use Google Wallet on my Google Pixel 3a
I have a Google Pixel 3a with Android 12, version March 2022.
I wanted to add a credit card to Gogle Wallet, and finally got this error (freely translated from french):

Cannot configure this device for contactless payment

Reading the associated help page I controlled that:

my device hasn't been rooted
NFC is active
but under Play Protect certification I see "The device is not certified"

This sounds pretty strange since it is a Google device!
On the web I found that exactly this version (12, March 2022) had a bug about the Google certification for this device (Pixel 3a).
So I presume it's the reason of my problem.
And probably next version corrects this bug, but ironically I was notified that this version is the very last update for my device!
Should I try to go back to an older version, and how to do it?
Or is there another solution?

I presume it isn't a rooted device. Please confirm. Maybe this fix will help//  See the Google forums addressing how

I confirm: device not rooted. And thanks for the link, but I don't understand how I can use it: its contents remain obscure to me!

I gave you two links, not sure which one is confusing you. If it is the second one (Google Forums) , then I am referring to this post by Jim Dantin

Might be helpful: Check & fix Play Protect certification status. I have Pixel 3a with the latest version, and the device is certified as normal, so I kind of doubt about the certification bug. Even if your device is not rooted, the bootloader might be unlocked.

@beeshyams Sorry, I didn't think to precise which link I cited, because I'd already  explored many Google resources so I stupidly gave up the first one. So it's the github one that doesn't help me for the moment. In the other hand, I now realize that the Google forum post is a good response to my question, in case it remains the last chance: I will use it if I can't get a simpler solution. Thanks.

@AndrewT. Thanks for this intersting link: it allowed me to ensure (even if a prior obvious) that the Pixel 3a is well known as a certified device. But now I'm stuck on "If it’s listed: To trigger the Play Protect certification check, tap Fix device issue.", because I don't see an option "Fix device issue" anywhere!
